# External Login and app login using firebase and web api 2

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-authentication, asp.net-web-api2, restful-authentication

I have created a web API application with OAuth2 (token bearer). The application is working fine. But now I want to implement google/facebook sign in with it so that both web and mobile users can use it.
After a bit of search, I found that firebase is a good option for this. But I am not able to find a way to authenticate the external token to the access token of the API. Pardon my understanding with firebase, I am completely new to it (just started a couple of hours ago). I have a few questions regarding this.

1. Do I have to change my current authentication method and use firebase authentication for internal login as well or is there some other way?
2. I am storing the data in an external DB. Do I will have to use the firebase db for the user to validate.
3. How do I validate the access token with external login token?

Kindly suggest. If there's any alternative approach, that too will be appreciated.

PS: I am using Owin for Authentication right now

Comment: I found something common in this https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/43 may this link helps you

Answer (score 0):

1. For use external login with firebase you need a token thats all.
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens
2. Not, you can use your un service for validate your user.
3. Please Read the link that i posted

Comment: Please read through: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Specifically, "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."